# Focus next Element in tabindex when pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Users on my application are used to press "Enter" when changing to the next input instead of "Tab", so I've been trying to change focus to the next Element in tabindex when pressing "Enter" instead of "Tab" given this code:

```
<div id="data">
  <input type="text" tabindex="0">
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly><br/>
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly>
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly><br/>
  <input type="text" tabindex="1">
  <input type="text" tabindex="2">
</div>
```

Now that I've achieved it I want to share my solution so the next person who has this problem finds the solution quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

In my case I aimed `$("#data")` for the function to trigger but you can use it with `$(window)`.

This function will get triggered on keydown, will check if the key is "Enter" (wich key code is 13), look for the next element of the focused element (`activeElement`) according to the tabindex and then will focus it.

```js
$("#data").keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    let active = document.activeElement;
    let target = $('[tabindex="' + (active.tabIndex + 1) + '"]');
    target.focus();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">
  <input type="text" tabindex="0">
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly><br/>
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly>
  <input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum" readonly><br/>
  <input type="text" tabindex="1">
  <input type="text" tabindex="2">
</div>
```

### Edit

In reference to @freedomn-m 's comment, this is his code to set the `tabindex` attribute on the **non-readonly** elements:

```
$(() => $("#data :input:not([readonly])").attr("tabIndex", (i, a) => i));
```

That's the code that I was using before:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let inputs = $('#data :input');
  let tabindex = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    if($(inputs[i]).attr("readonly") !== "readonly"){
      inputs[i].setAttribute("tabindex", tabindex);
      tabindex++;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: interesting function actually, thanx for contribution

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you'll have to *hardcode every tab index* on *every element* - that's generally unmaintainable.  If you have already done this, then fine.  Otherwise look for any of the other solutions [already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+move+next+enter)

Comment: @freedomn-m that's true, but you can add the `tabindex` attribute with a `$( document ).ready()`` function on the non-readonly elements (at least thats what I've done) I'll check other solutions anyways (haven't found them before) thanks for your link!

Comment: `$(() => $("#data [readonly]:input").attr("tabIndex", (i, a) => i));`

Comment: @freedomn-m really interesting!! But it's doing the opposite, I want to add `tabindex` to the ones that **don't** have the `readonly` attribute, is there any way of doing it in your way?

Comment: `$("#data :input:not([readonly])")` (not tested, I'd probably use .filter() myself)

Comment: Works! Amazing!